# Latex multicolumn makes bottom column text left-aligned

Tags: tables

[image]

How do I fix the bottom row so that all of the text on the bottom row floats to the left?

My code:

```
  \vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{Lorem Ipsum university} & Lorem Ipsum location \\
      \small PhD. in Electrical Engineering \& Computer Science & \textit{\small Aug. 2019 -- Present} \\
      \small GPA: 4.0/4.0 \\
      \multicolumn{2}{l} Lorem ipsum testing testing
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you had omitted the braces

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\vspace{-1pt}\item
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{Lorem Ipsum university} & Lorem Ipsum location \\
      \small PhD. in Electrical Engineering \& Computer Science & \textit{\small Aug. 2019 -- Present} \\
      \small GPA: 4.0/4.0 \\
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{Lorem ipsum testing testing}
    \end{tabular*}\vspace{-5pt}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```